# How to sort 'paired' vectors in R

Tags: r, sorting, vector

Suppose I have two independent vectors ``x`and`y` of the same length:

```
   x         y
   1         0.12
   2         0.50
   3         0.07
   4         0.10
   5         0.02
```

I want to sort the elements in `y` in decreasing order, and sort the values in `x` in a way that allows me to keep the correspondence between the two vectors, which would lead to this:

```
   x         y
   2         0.50
   1         0.12
   4         0.10
   3         0.07
   5         0.02
```

I'm new to `r`, and although I know it has a built in `sort` function that allows me to sort the elements in `y`, I don't know how to make it sort both. The only thing I can think of involves doing a `for` cycle to "manually" sort `x` by checking the original location of the elements in `y`:

```
for(i in 1:length(ysorted)){
    xsorted[i]=x[which(ysorted[i]==y)]
}
```

which is very ineffective.

Comment: Use `df2 <- df1[order(-df1$y),]`

Comment: This is what data structures are for. Put them in a data frame. Sort the data frame. `my_data = data.frame(x, y)`. `my_data = my_data[order(-my_data$y), ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dplyr` :

```
dat <- structure(list(x = 1:5, 
y = c(0.12, 0.5, 0.07, 0.1, 0.02)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

library(dplyr)
dat %>% arrange(desc(y))
  x    y
1 2 0.50
2 1 0.12
3 4 0.10
4 3 0.07
5 5 0.02
```

In `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[order(-y)]
   x    y
1: 2 0.50
2: 1 0.12
3: 4 0.10
4: 3 0.07
5: 5 0.02
```

*Speed Comparison*

Three solutions have already been offered in the answers, namely : `base`, `dplyr`, and `data.table`. Similar to this case, in many cases in R programming, you can achieve the exactly same result by different approaches.

In case you need to get a comparison of the approaches based on how fast each approach is executed in R, you can use `microbenchmark` from `{microbenchmark}` package (again, there are also some other ways to do this).
Here is an example. In this example each approach is run 1000 times, and then the summaries of the required time are reported.

```
microbenchmark(
     base_order = dat[order(-dat$y),],
     dplyr_order = dat %>% arrange(desc(y)),
     dt_order = as.data.table(dat)[order(-y)], 
     times = 1000
 )

#Unit: microseconds
#        expr    min      lq      mean  median      uq     max neval
#  base_order   42.0   63.25   97.2585   79.45  100.35  6761.8  1000
# dplyr_order 1244.5 1503.45 1996.4406 1689.85 2065.30 16868.4  1000
#    dt_order  261.3  395.85  583.9086  487.35  587.70 39294.6  1000
```

The results show that, for your case, `base_order` is the fastest. It executed the column ordering about 20 times faster than `dplyr_order` did, and about 6 times faster than `dt_order` did.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `order` in `base R`

```
df2 <- df1[order(-df1$y),]
```

-output

```
df2
  x    y
2 2 0.50
1 1 0.12
4 4 0.10
3 3 0.07
5 5 0.02
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = 1:5, y = c(0.12, 0.5, 0.07, 0.1, 0.02)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```